# Getter for ENUM values

Tags: java, enums, libgdx

I'm trying to get a variable, or an enum out of an enum(I'm not sure what to call it).

So this is my enum.

```
public enum fruits {

//ID 0
banana(0,250, 150f, 400f, "Assassin"),
//ID 1
apple(1, 300f, 200f, 600f, "Fighter");





private float atk, def, hp;
private final String Style;
private int ID;


Ship(int id,  float attack, float defence, float health, String fightStyle) {
    atk = attack;
    def = defence;
    hp = health;
    Style = fightStyle;
    ID = id;

}

public String getLore() {
    return Lore;
}

public float getAtk() {
    return atk;
}

public float getPen() {
    return pen;
}

public float getDef() {
    return def;
}

public float getHp() {
    return hp;
}

public String getStyle() {
    return Style;
}

public int getID() {
    return ID;
}
```

So in this class I'm trying to use the enum to create a player with certain enum stats. Let's say I make a player and he's aa banana, he would have banana stats and be able to upgrade them.

Here is where I try to do that.

```
public class Player implements BaseEntity{

Fruitfruit;

//STATS
float atk;
float def;
float hp;


public Player(Fruitfruit) {
    this.fruit = fruit;
    atk = fruit.getAtk();
    def = fruit.getDef();
    hp = fruit.getHp();


}

@Override
public float getHP() {
    return hp;
}

@Override
public float getDef() {
    return def;
}

@Override
public float getAtk() {
    return atk;
}

@Override
public float getPen() {
    return pen;
}

@Override
public int getFruit() {
    return fruit.getID();
}

@Override
public String getFruitType() {
    return fruit.getStyle();
}



@Override
public void setFruit() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

I want the player to have banana stats and be able to level up those stats. I also want the player to have a certain fruit. Let's say you upgrade from banana to apple, your stats are equal to the apple.

Comment: try `fruits.banana.getAtk();`

Comment: Thanks, also I want to get the fruit type to see what fruit I am

Comment: :) a game about fruits. this will be cool

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this.

Player

```
public Fruit getFruit() {
    return fruit;
}

public void upgradePlayer(Fruit fruit) {
    this.fruit = fruit;
    atk = fruit.getAtk();
    def = fruit.getDef();
    hp = fruit.getHp();
}
```

Sample implementation of upgrade player

```
if (!player.getFruit().equals(Fruit.apple)) {
    player.upgradePlayer(Fruit.apple);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To refer to an `Enum` value, simply use:

```
Fruits.BANANA
```

For example, you can instantiate a `Player` using the following line:

```
final Player player = new Player(Fruits.BANANA);
```

Answer (score 0):

And if you at some point get tired of using enums, concider integer constants:

```
public static final int FRUIT_BANANA = 0;
public static final int FRUIT_APPLE = 1;

private int fruit = FRUIT_BANANA;
```